# jQuery window resizing messes up css outside query

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I am not sure if this question has been answered here before, but when I use jquery(window) as a condition to change css of a div, the rest of the css for that div gets messed up outside the query when resizing.

For example, in the code below, I am trying to reposition Div A when the window width is greater than 767px and less than 800px.  The only time this code works perfectly is if I load the page within this width.  However, if I move out of the specified width, for example, 800 or greater, DivA css gets messed up.  If I load the page in 800 or greater, DivA css is fine, however, if I then scroll into 767-800, the code below doesn't work.  Basically, what I am trying to do is have the code sensitive to resizing.

```
if ($(window).width() > 767 && $(window).width() < 800){
 $('.DivA').css({
  transform: 'translateX(180px)',
  MozTransform: 'translateX(180px)',
  WebkitTransform: 'translateX(180px)',
  msTransform: 'translateX(180px)'
 })
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the above code? With `$(window).resize()`?

Comment: Yes, even if I call it on document ready, same problem

Comment: You'll probably see more help if you post the HTML containing `.DivA` along with any external css that might be getting applied to `.DivA`. You can also post it in as a runnable code snippet so others can see what you're seeing.

Comment: I tried to recreate it in a fiddle and the problem wasn't quite showing and I believe it originally resulted from the use of media queries.  I designed a work around by just setting css for windows >800 and < 767